# "Dog" meaning in old English language

Tags: british-english

I read these sentences in "The life of Samuel Johnson":

> JOHNSON: You HAVE Lord Kames. Keep him; ha, ha, ha! We don't envy you him. Do you ever see Dr. Robertson?
>   BOSWELL: Yes, Sir.
>   JOHNSON: Does the dog talk of me?
>   BOSWELL: Indeed, Sir, he does, and loves you.

Does **"dog"** in this context mean the person Dr. Robertson, or is there an archaic meaning to imply *best friend*?

Answer (score 2):

From **[The Life of Samuel Johnson, LL. D. by James Boswell](https://books.google.com/books?id=TmShu9cK3IUC&lpg=PA247&ots=UnWE4BUptg&dq=literary%20use%20of%20dog%20robertson%20by%20samuel%20johnson&pg=PA247#v=onepage&q=%20dog%20Dr.%20robertson&f=false)** we learn the depths of Dr Johnson's contempt of Dr. Robertson:

> It is to be regretted that Mr. Boswell should have persisted in
>   repeating these assertions.Dr, Johnson, on every occasion, seems to
>   have expressed a great contempt for Dr. Robertson's works - very
>   unjustly indeed; but however Mr. Boswell might lament Johnson's
>   prejudice, he was in fact not justified in thus repeatedly misstating
>   the fact. [text goes on to cite 2 more examples where Boswell further
>   suppresses and misrepresents Johnson's opinions of Dr. Robertson]

With this contempt in mind, the sense of:  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56405?rskey=bjB4Wx&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> a term of reproach or abuse: a worthless or contemptible person; a
>   wretch, a cur.

seems to set the stage for supporting a contemptible person.

And early use cited:

> c1330  Richard Coer de Lyon  in Englische Studien (1885)    Drisses
>   now ȝour mangunel..& scheteþ to hem wiþ alblast, Þe teyled **doggen**
>   to agast.

Dog has many senses and some date to ~1200 A.D. Ugly ladies and rotten gentlemen have senses of "dog" and "sup, dog?" is modern and benign. But here (your question) the snarky, negative connotation cited is, IMHO, in use.

Comment: Not necessarily. Oxford Dictionaries (via Google) gives "Used to refer to a person of a specified kind in a tone of playful reproof, commiseration, or congratulation. -
"your historian is a dull dog" ". I know Dr Johnson doesn't 'specify the kind of person' Dr Robertson is, but he could be using the term in this sense.

Comment: @KateBunting so noted - further edit my answer to add support ... in the case of Johnson's use of dog and Dr. Robertson.

Comment: 'The old sea dog'. I'm with Kate.

Comment: Ibf, I dispute the claim that the snarky meaning is in use: the prose is jovial, and Boswell says 'he loves you'

Comment: @marcellothearcane see my recent edit showing Boswell's frequent suppression of Johnson's contempt of Robertson.  A few more DV, and my answer shall go away ... lol

Comment: Oh okay, I wasn't aware of the book, hence I disputed rather than denied